# lucene join query

Tags: lucene

Is there a way to issue join queries (http://www.searchworkings.org/blog/-/blogs/query-time-joining-in-lucene) in lucene without directly using Query API? Is it possible to issue query in text form for this requirement? For example:

```
title:derivatives  join(comments:great)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Solr (4.0, not released yet) has a [query parser](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join) which can handle join queries.

Comment: do you know if this will be part of lucene 4.0 as well?

Comment: I can't tell, but I think it is unlikely to be part of the default query parser.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, I think you want a query like 'title:derivatives AND comments:great'. Or you can use code like 'queryParser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.Operator.AND)' to change the default conjunction operator to AND instead of OR ('OR' is used by default unless you tell Lucene otherwise).

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. I wanted information about joins (index-time or query-time)

Comment: ...and I didn't understand your question after all. (He needs to join separate Lucene documents in a query (for those of you playing the home game here).)